# using (ngModelChange) twice

Tags: angular

I use angular 2 multiselect dropdown and it is performing the way i expected it to.

I have a doubt with the below mentioned usage :

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown #dropdown [options]="dataObject" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)" (ngModelChange)='dropdown.clearSearch({})' [ngModel]="dataSelected"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Why is it that there is no error thrown for using ngModelChange twice,
Since ,i've already bound ngModelchange with onSelect($event) ?

Thanks ,

Comment: Why do you think it should throw error?

Comment: @yurzui , since ngModel is bound to dataSelected , and dataSelected is changing only once , shouldn't ngModelChange be fired only once ?

Comment: It will fire as many times as we have subscribed

Comment: oh okay . Thank you for clearing my doubts :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the `ngModel` [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.3/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L124) you will see that `ngModelChange` is Angular's EventEmmiter.

You subscribed to this emmiter twice. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: We can change `ngModelChange` to `click` and there will be also nothing wrong with that. addEventListener lets us opportunity
 to handle two events

Comment: Thank you for the reply @taras-d , this cleared my doubt .

Answer (score -3):

You can set the only one ngmodelChange;

Comment: No , that is exactly why i asked the question.